# How to add a delay in async.js iterator (Node)

Tags: node.js, async.js

I'm writing a crawler in Node and just discovered the fantastic [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async) library. I'd like to not overwhelm the servers I crawl. So I want to introduce a delay between iterations. What is the best way to do this? Can I just call callback() from the iterator inside a setTimeout?

Comment: Please show a representative version of your code.  It's way, way easier to answer questions like this in the context of your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the completion of any async task with the Async library is always signaled by calling a completion callback, you can simply delay calling that by putting it in a `setTimeout()`.  Here's an example, adapted from an example in the async doc:

```
async.eachSeries(hugeArray, function iterator(item, callback) {
    doSomeIO(item, function(err, result) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // process err or result here
            callback(err);
        }, 500);
    });
  }
}, function done() {
  //...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

That will work, you can use Async Series like so :

```
async.eachSeries(TheUrl, function (eachUrl, done) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var url = 'www.myurl.com='+eachUrl;
        request(url, function(error, resp, body) { 
            if (error) return callback(error); 
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            //Some calculations again...
            done();
        });
    }, 10000);
}, function (err) {
    if (!err) callback();
});
```